# Why did this "First Post" question appear in my to-be-reviewed queue after being one month old?

Tags: bug, support, review

A few minutes ago, [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115825/how-can-i-save-a-score-for-a-web-game-made-in-unity-and-load-it-when-the-game-st) appeared in my to-be-reviewed queue, classified as a "First Post" - and thus waiting for a review.

Nothing wrong about the classification. After checking, one sees that it was indeed the first post by its author (from January 29nd). However, what I did not understand was why did it appear in my to-be-reviewed queue today.

I check my review queue pretty much every day and solve anything pendent so to be always with 0 posts in any of the review categories I have access to. So, that question has not been in my "First Posts" to-be-reviewed queue in the past month. It just showed up today (by the way, after the author already has 4 more questions already posted in this site).

Not that I am saying anything is wrong. I would just like to understand when something like that can happen, so I can better learn of the details of the functioning of this site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "First Posts" queue isn't just "first post a user made." There are other criteria which aren't very clearly documented (possibly because they're often tweaked to tune the results).

Some of those criteria have [in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235024/old-first-post-reviews-on-sites-without-audits-enabled) included reputation or post score metrics, activity surrounding other posts (generally deletion) et cetera.

It's also worth noting that when you get a review, you "lock" it for a brief window of time until you action it or skip it. If you do neither, the review will time out and go back into the queue. The timeout isn't very long though, so that's unlikely to be what happened here given it's been weeks since the original post.